# How can I Convert Long Dates into Years?

Tags: stata

I have imported an Excel file into Stata containing a string variable with dates in the Month/Day/Year Format, as following:

```
     +--------------------------+
     |     country     Election |
     |--------------------------|
  1. | New Zealand   11/29/1969 |
  2. | New Zealand   11/25/1972 |
  3. | New Zealand   11/27/1999 |
  4. | New Zealand   11/25/1972 |
  5. | New Zealand   09/17/2005 |
     +--------------------------+
```

My intention is to transform the date, so that only the year appears.

I have used `gen year = date(Election, "MDY")` to create a new date variable with the float type. However, I don't know how to proceed. How could I transform these dates into years only?

Comment: Check out `help datetime` especially the section on "SIF-to-SIF conversion" which is what you want to do - convert from "date" to "yearly". I recommend you `generate` a new variable rather than `replace` the existing variable.

Comment: Thank you! I checked it out and ran the command: generate Year_only = yofd( year). It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer, but we'll spell it out for the benefit of any others interested.

Your variable `year` is misnamed, as it is a daily date variable. I'd recommend using the function `daily()` rather than `date()` to underline what is happening. It's the same code under different guises. Then you need `yofd()` to convert.

```
clear 
input str11 (country Election) 
"New Zealand"   "11/29/1969"
"New Zealand"   "11/25/1972"
"New Zealand"   "11/27/1999"
"New Zealand"   "11/25/1972"
"New Zealand"   "09/17/2005"
end 
gen dailydate = daily(Election, "MDY") 
format dailydate %td 
gen yeardate = yofd(dailydate) 
list 


     +-------------------------------------------------+
     |     country     Election   dailydate   yeardate |
     |-------------------------------------------------|
  1. | New Zealand   11/29/1969   29nov1969       1969 |
  2. | New Zealand   11/25/1972   25nov1972       1972 |
  3. | New Zealand   11/27/1999   27nov1999       1999 |
  4. | New Zealand   11/25/1972   25nov1972       1972 |
  5. | New Zealand   09/17/2005   17sep2005       2005 |
     +-------------------------------------------------+
```